# writing xml contents to a file

Tags: c#

How to write the contents of the "XmlNodeList" in a separate xml file(ie.,the contents should be appended at the end of a file,if the file already contains some text)?

Comment: Appending at the end of an existing file will cause that file to not be a valid xml file. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: yes.I have a list of xmlfiles generated in my application.I have to take some elements in all the files and create a new file.thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the XML ( I assume you do!) you can do the following steps:

1. Create XmlDocument object of the file you need to modify
2. Create the XmlNodeList ready ( you have that already)
3. Use the AppendChild, InsertAfter or InsertBerfore methods ( these methods accept only XmlNode so you will have to iterate)
4. Save the XmlDocument

Hope this helps,
Regards,
Abdel Olakara

Answer (score 0):

Load the XML document. Find the node where you want to insert new block. Insert the block. Write the XML to the file.

Use XmlDocument class for this purpose. Check MSDN for examples.